# Me sale error HTTP ERROR 500 en formularo php y msql

Tags: sql

Muy buenas. Estoy intentando hacer un formulario de registro de datos con Mysql pero me sale error HTTP ERROR 500 al presionar enviar datos.  ¿Si no es mucha molestia, me podríais decir que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias de antemano.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formulario de Registro SCIII</title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h2>Formulario de Registro</h2>
 <div class="group">
 <form action="registro.php" method="POST">
 <label for="Nombres">Nombres <span>(requerido)</span></label>
 <input type="text" name="Nombres" class="form-input" required/>

 <label for="Correo_electronico">Email <span>(requerido)</span></label>
 <input type="email" name="Correo_electronico" class="form-input" />

 <label for="Apellido1">Apellido <span>(requerido)</span></label>
 <input type="text" name="Apellido1" class="form-input" required/>

 <label for="Apellido2">Segundo apellido <span>(requerido)</span></label>
 <input type="text" name="Apellido2" class="form-input" / required>

 <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Registrarme!!" /> 
 </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**REGISTRO.PHP**

```
    <?php
 require_once(’funciones.php’);
 conectar(’MISITIO.COM’, ’USUARIO’, ’CONTRASEÑA’, ’univerec_registro_usuarios’);

 //Recibir
 $nombre = strip_tags($_POST[’Nombres’]);
 $email = strip_tags($_POST[’Correo_electronico’]);
 $apellido1 = strip_tags($_POST[’Apellido1’]);
 $apellido2 = strip_tags($_POST[’Apellido2’]);
 $query = @mysql_query(’SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user="’.mysql_real_escape_string($user).’"’);
 if($existe = @mysql_fetch_object($query))
 {
 echo ’El usuario ’.$user. ’ya existe.’;
 }
 else{
 $meter = @mysql_query(’INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, email, user, password) values ("’.mysql_real_escape_string($nombre).’", "’.mysql_real_escape_string($email).’", "’.mysql_real_escape_string($user).’", "’.mysql_real_escape_string($password).’")’);
 if($meter)
 {
 echo ’Usuario registrado con exito’;
 }else{
 echo ’Hubo un error en el registro.’;
 }
 }
 ?>
```

**FUNCIONES.PHP**

```
    <?php
 function conectar($servidor, $user, $pass, $name)
 {
 $con = @mysql_connect($servidor, $user, $pass);
 @mysql_select_db($name, $con); 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: pueden ser mil cosas... usas windows o linux?

Comment: Uso windows, pero no es un servidor local, mi sitio esta montado en un hosting.

Comment: ok para empezar quita as comillas ´ por estas '

Comment: Si hago eso deja de salir el error, osea, sale todo en blanco.

Comment: por que usas el `@` en tus funciones, sabes que eso es para que no se te muestren los errores? lo cual no ayuda a identificar el error?

Comment: el error 500 se deber a una incompatibilidad de la funciones que utiliza php, en la version 7 el mysql_query fue quitado por seguridad y fue remplazado por mysqli_query() http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Hice el cambio que dices pero aun asi me sigue arrojando el error 500. He intentado cambiando las comillas como lo indica el comentario anterior pero todo sigue igual.

Comment: He visto tu código pero no veo en donde declaras la variable $user, ahora por otra parte, en apache cuando se produce un error 500 genera un archivo error_log en donde te puedes dar idea de que es lo que en realidad lo está generando.